# Relationship not saved in SDN 6 (Spring data neo4j)

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Hello have problems with saving relation ships with NEO4J and Spring, I can save relationships when I don't use a class with `@RelationProperties`, but whenever I want to use that class the relationships are not even created.

I am using  Neo4j 4.3.7-community edition in a docker container
And in my pom.xml i have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to do something like this
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8pHF.png)

I have this bit of code :

starting node

```java
...
    @Relationship(type = "VISITS",direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Visits> visits;

    public void visitPOI(Visits visit) {
        if(visits == null) {
            visits = new HashSet<>();
        }
        visits.add(visit);
    }
...
```

My relation

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class Visits {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Property private String description;

    @TargetNode private PointOfInterest poi;

    public Visits(String description, PointOfInterest p){
        this.description = description;
        this.poi = p;
    }
...
```

and the destination node

```
...
@Node
public class PointOfInterest {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;



    @Property private String name;
    @Property private double lat;
    @Property private double lng;

    public PointOfInterest() { }

//getters and setters
...
```

And this in a service

```
...
    public void saveRelation(String username, Visits v ){

        User u = userRepository.findByUserName(username);

        Optional<PointOfInterest> poi = pointOfInterestRepository.findById(v.getPoi().getId());
        v.setPoi(poi.get());
        u.visitPOI(v);
        userRepository.save(u);
    }
...
```

and the JSON I post

```
{
    "description":"Nice trip",
    "poi":{
        "id":"Uster"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Data REST or Spring Web/MVC?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. if you remove `@RelationshipProperties`, SDN treats the class as target nodes, and build the relationship to the target nodes without any properties. When having `@RelationshipProperties`, nothing happens, not even the relationship is built

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RelationshipId` on id field of `@RelationshipProperties` as follow

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class Visits {
    @RelationshipId
    private long id;

    @Property private String description;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with persisting relationship properties using `@RelationshipProperty` annotated class. Finally, I discovered that the issue is due to the implicit conversion between long and Long. Changing `@RelationshipId private long id;` to `@RelationshipId private Long id;` inside the `@RelationshipProperty` annotated class will do the trick. This appears to be a bug in SDN, it should report an error instead.